# Caching the Palette generated from a Bitmap

Tags: android, android-glide, palette

I am writing an application that displays a grid of images in a `RecyclerView`. Images are loaded using Glide v4, using the content Uri of that image from the MediaStore.

For each image, the corresponding color `Palette` is generated using `PaletteBitmapTranscoder`, a custom implementation of `ResourceTranscoder` as advised by the official [Glide documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets#palette-example):

```
data class PaletteBitmap(val palette: Palette, val bitmap: Bitmap)

class PaletteBitmapResource(
    private val paletteBitmap: PaletteBitmap,
    private val bitmapPool: BitmapPool
) : Resource<PaletteBitmap> {

    override fun getResourceClass() = PaletteBitmap::class.java

    override fun get() = this.paletteBitmap

    override fun getSize() = Util.getBitmapByteSize(paletteBitmap.bitmap)

    override fun recycle() = bitmapPool.put(paletteBitmap.bitmap)
}

class PaletteBitmapTranscoder(
    private val bitmapPool: BitmapPool
) : ResourceTranscoder<Bitmap, PaletteBitmap> {

    override fun transcode(toTranscode: Resource<Bitmap>, options: Options): Resource<PaletteBitmap> {
        val bitmap = toTranscode.get()
        val palette = Palette.from(bitmap).generate()
        val result = PaletteBitmap(palette, bitmap)
        return PaletteBitmapResource(result, bitmapPool)
    }
}
```

Here is how the PaletteBitmapTranscoder is configured in the GlideModule:

```
@GlideModule
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun isManifestParsingEnabled() = false

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        // Calculate the color Palette associated with the loaded Bitmap
        registry.register(
            Bitmap::class.java, PaletteBitmap::class.java,
            PaletteBitmapTranscoder(glide.bitmapPool)
        )
    }
}
```

Here is how I load images in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment).`as`(PaletteBitmap::class.java)
    .load(model.iconUri)
    .into(object : ImageViewTarget<PaletteBitmap>(imageView) {

        override fun setResource(resource: PaletteBitmap?) {
            if (resource != null) {
                useThatPalette(resource.palette)
                super.view.setImageBitmap(resource.bitmap)
            }
        }
}
```

This is working as expected.

## The question

I read that Glide caches images that has been loaded into a disk and a memory cache. As I am loading a lot of images in a `RecyclerView` and generating a color `Palette` for each, I'd like Glide to store instances of `Palette` in the cache, along their corresponding `Bitmap`.

It looks like Glide already puts `PaletteBitmap` instances in memory cache, but I'd like to put them also in the disk cache so that each `Palette` is generated only once for each `Bitmap`.

I've heard of Glide's `ResourceEncoder` but can't figure out how to use it in my case.
Is it possible to store transcoded resources in Glide's disk cache, and if possible, how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Glide v4?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using Glide 4.6.1.